# How to lazy load background images in react using react-lazy-load-image-component?

Tags: css, reactjs, image, optimization, lazy-loading

```
<div className="background-image"
   style={{backgroundImage: `url(${imageUrl})`}} />
</div>
```

Also How to create common components to make them reusable for multiple images

Thank You.

Comment: A simple example is give in the [npm link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-lazy-load-image-component)